# python2.7: matplotlib in jupyter notebook can't use qt

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I've installed `python2.7` and installed `matplotlib` using pip. When I execute:

```
% matplotlib qt
```

It get the error:

```
No module named pyqt4, pyqt5...
```

So I installed `pyqt4` using `.whl` file, and the error becomes:

```
No module named pyqt5
```

I've searched that `pyqt5` can be easy installed using `pip3 install pyqt5`, but not for `pip`.

Also I remembered that I have solved this problem by downgrading `jupyter` before but I can't remember it exactly.

I have searched the web for a while but can't find a solution, how can I get rid of this error in a most simple way?

[image]

Comment: Which OS are you using? Are you using virtualenv or not?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Windows, no virtualenv. Actually, this problem happens both in windows and mac, and mac is fixed and it is OK now. I also have fixed windows before, but I can't remember the method.

Comment: Why not install pyside instead?  I just did `pip install pyside` and it works for me after that

Comment: @TarunLalwani not working for me. still `No module named pyqt5`

Comment: Then there are other things you can try. Set a environment variable in windows `MPLBACKEND` with value as `Qt4Agg`. See this for more available backend https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend. Also you can try `%matplotlib qt4` instead of `%matplotlib qt`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Use `%matplotlib qt4` warns me `Warning: Cannot change to a different GUI toolkit: qt4. Using qt instead.` I've also download the matplotlibrc file and change it to `qt4agg`, not working. still warns `can't find qt5`

Comment: @TarunLalwani see the uploaded picture

Comment: @TarunLalwani Change environment variable works, please make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to specify the backend for matplotlib

### Using Environment Variable

Set a environment variable in windows `MPLBACKEND` with value as `Qt4Agg`.

See this for more available backend

https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#what-is-a-backend

### Using names

Also you can try `%matplotlib qt4` instead of `%matplotlib qt`